# Spring ReactiveCrudRepository doesn't support PUT? TransientDataAccessException

Tags: java, spring, rest, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'm using Spring to build a simple Web app.  At the front end I have a REST api, which has a PUT method like this: `/api/v1/apple/{id}`

When the call comes in to this endpoint, the body is deserialised to an `Apple`.

In the [spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6) for PUT it says: *"The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the supplied Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to an already existing resource, the enclosed entity SHOULD be considered as a modified version of the one residing on the origin server. If the Request-URI does not point to an existing resource, and that URI is capable of being defined as a new resource by the requesting user agent, the origin server can create the resource with that URI."*

So if apple 21 exists in the DB (and is therefore reachable at `/api/v1/apple/21`), it should be replaced with the one in the request.
But if it doesn't, a new one should be created, as per the apple in the request, with primary key 21 and URI `/api/v1/apple/21`.

The problem is that the `ReactiveCrudRepository` seems not to support this.

According to the [release notes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/current/reference/html/#new-features.1-0-0), since spring-data r2dbc 1.0.0, if you call `save()` and the row doesn't exist in the database, it throws a `TransientDataAccessException`.  I see the following:

```
Failed to updated table [apples].  Row with Id [21] does not exist.    
org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: Failed to updated table [apples].  Row with Id [21] does not exist.
  at app//org.springframework.data.r2dbc.core.R2dbcEntityTemplate.lambda$doUpdate$14(R2dbcEntityTemplate.java:707)
.....
```

So if I supply an ID for my new Apple, I can't create it - at least not using `ReactiveCrudRepository`.  If I remove the ID from the POJO first, it will create it, but with an assigned ID - in other words calling `PUT /api/v1/apple/21` will result in creation of an apple, but with some other id (not 21).

What am I missing here?  There appear to be no alternatives to the save() method which behave the way I need.

Comment: what you are missing is quite obvious, the PUT method is applied to a REST api, not a database api. The Crud repository handles CRUD operations, Create, Read, Update, Delete... there is no P in CRUD, otherwise it yould be named CRUPD

Comment: If it's so easy, can you give a code example?  I fail to see how to use spring reactive crud repository behind a spring REST API to support PUT.

Comment: please read my comment, and tell me where i said the implementation was easy? i wrote, that CRUD does not include PUT, as the name states CRUD is create read update delete.... no PUT... if you want put, you need to implement it by accepting a PUT request in your REST api, then write the buisness logic as you want it, and then use the CRUD repository to update your data.

Comment: My point is that using the ReactiveCrudRepository for persistence, it's impossible to write such business logic.  The service layer receives an Apple object with a primary key set.  The only way to write that to the DB is to call save().  But if the DB entry doesn't already exist, you get an exception.  So how can you write the Apple to the DB in such a scenario, while maintaining the primary key as sent by the client?